# twitter and European Championship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, rubygems

I'm using mac and installed the twitter gem.

Now, how can I access the advanced search of Twitter for downloading all the tweets about the final of the European Championship? Thanks.

```
gem 'twitter'
gem 'twitter-text'
```

This is the Tweets Controller:

```
def index
   @tweets = Tweet.all
end
```

the Tweet Model

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Twitter::Extractor
    def extract_tags
        extract_hashtags(self.post)
    end
end
```

And the View:

```
<% @tweets.map(&:extract_tags).flatten %>
```

And the routes

```
get "index" => "tweets#index"
get "tweets#index"
```

It does not work! I don't no why!

Comment: This is not a code factory. What have you tried?

Comment: Right now there isn't anything *like* enough information here for anyone to help you. Also, before asking how to get a library to do something, you should spend a little time thinking about what it is you actually want to *do*. Suppose you were using only the twitter web interface, what would you do?

Comment: Better, but "It does not work" is not a useful bug report. Of the [Three Parts To Every Good Bug Report](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000029.html), you've told us the Steps to Reproduce, but not the Expected Result or the Actual result.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should just look at the [twitter gem documentation](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter) and the `search` method in it.

Answer (score 1):

Your best friend is google, dont forget that mate. There is a nice article/tutorial about tweet fetching that you should look in to: [Tweet Fetching](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/intro_tweet_fetch/).